# How to properly extend classes in python and the use parent?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to extend the class `Client` from `SUDS` module... For example i have this simple code which works fine

```
client = Client(wsdl, username = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD, headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'}, plugins = [VapixHelper()])

rules = client.service.GetActionRules()
```

And so i need to add some extra methods for this class so i try to do it like this:

```
class Vapix(Client):
    def __init__(self, args):
        globals().update(vars(args))
        USERNAME, PASSWORD = user_data.split(':')
        super(Vapix, self).__init__(wsdl, username = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD, headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'}, plugins = [VapixHelper()])

    def setActionStatus(self, status):
        print super(Vapix, self).service.GetActionRules()
```

And i get this error instead of the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vapix.py", line 42, in <module>
    client.setActionStatus(True)
  File "vapix.py", line 36, in setActionStatus
    print super(Vapix, self).service.GetActionRules()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'service'
```

Comment: Just use `self.service`.

Comment: @BrenBarn nice one, thanks... May be you can provide some info where is the difference between `super(Vapix, self)` and `self` when need to call parent class ?

Comment: you may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods

Comment: You're not calling the parent class there, you're accessing an attribute of the *instance*.  As loong as you properly call the superclass *methods* (like you're doing with `__init__`), the right attributes will just be there on the instance and you can use them as normal.

Answer (score 2):

You are not overriding a `service()` method, so you don't need to use `super()` to find an original method; remove the `super()` call and access the attribute directly on `self` instead:

```
def setActionStatus(self, status):
    print self.service.GetActionRules()
```

`super()` is only needed if you need to search the base classes (in Method Resolution Order, MRO) for a method (or other descriptor object), often because the current class has redefined that name.

If you need to call a base class `foo` but the current class implements a `foo` method, then you cannot use `self.foo()` and you need to use `super()` instead. You *had* to use `super()` for `__init__` for example; your derived class has its own `__init__` method, so calling `self.__init__()` would recursively call that same method, but `super(Vapix, self).__init__()` works because `super()` looks at the MRO of `self`, finds `Vapix` in that ordering, then goes looking for the next class that has an `__init__` method.

Here `service` is an *instance attribute*; it is defined directly on `self` and isn't even a method.

Comment: yeah, already understood this... One move thing on your answer... What should i do if i wanted to override parent method?

Comment: @Kirix: *then* you name the method the same and use `super()` to invoke the parent method still.